# Ruby until always validates as false?

Tags: ruby, loops

So I've written this piece of code to play around with numbers and the until loop:

```
number = rand(10)
puts number

puts "Guess the number"
guess = gets.chomp


until guess == number
  puts "Guess again!"
  guess = gets.chomp
end

puts "You've guessed it right! The number is #{guess}
```

But for some reason it it always stuck in the until loop and I am not sure why. I puts the random number to know that i guess right and try out the code. I'm completely new to Ruby, So I guess it's a very obvious thing I am missing, but I just dont see it.

From my point of view, whenever I prompt for the guess again, that guess that validated by the until loop with `until guess == number`.

Who can help me clear this up?

Comment: You are comparing a number with a character.  Change `gets.chomp` to `gets.chomp.to_i` (or just `gets.to_i`) or `number = rand(10).to_s` would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple, and that is you're failing to cast the user input into an integer.

i.e. if I write

```
number = gets.chomp
```

and I type `1` for the number, then the `number` variable will equal the *string* `"1"`, not the *integer* `1`.

To fix this, just use `guess = gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: I knew it was something very obvious. Strings don't compare to ints even if the string only consist out if nummeric values. Didn't think of that. Thx!

Comment: No problem. It's custom to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I know. I will be able to do so in exactly 9 minutes :P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `guess = gets.chomp`(which will return a string of the user input), use `guess = gets.to_i` (which will convert user input into integer)
`to_i` method will convert the element into integer and will drop `/n` character since it's not part of the integer. Don't need to add `.chomp` method.